# How to set startup executable for a VC++ project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

This is a pretty novice question, but I've been trying to build and run Ghostscript using Visual Studio 2012. When I try to do "Start Debugging" or "Start Without Debugging" the project builds fine, but then I get the error "Unable to start program 'C:...\ghostscript-9.07\debugobj\ghostscript.exe"

The project never outputs a ghostscript.exe file when compiled. It outputs "gswin32.exe" in the debugbuild directory, which is the file I need to run after compilation. I think Visual Studio is looking for debugobj\ghostscript.exe because the project is named "ghostscript" and debugobj is configured as the output directory.

Is there some kind of configuration setting I can set to specify that debugbuild\gswin32.exe is the executable that should be run after building?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. From the Project menu go into Properties and review the settings in the Debug section.